# How to link multiple Docker webserver containers running on different ports to different url paths?

Tags: http, docker

If I have two Docker containers (A & B) running with their ports published on
81 and 82, how can I link these these containers to a third container (C)
running on port 80 that will map different url paths to these different
containers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dockerfu](https://github.com/FrozenRidge/dockerfu) gives you auto-magical routing to containers based on URLs using a naming convention of docker containers. It is designed more for public facing containers rather than links between containers but you may be able to get it to work for internal links also.

Other than that HAProxy and Nginx are good solutions but a little more manual.

If you use [Nginx](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/nginx/), you can add the following configuration to a file. Editing the URLs, URIs and IPs as needed.

```
server{
  server_name A.whatever.com;
  location /AAAA {
    proxy_pass http://192.100.100.100:81;
  }
}

server{
  server_name B.whatever.com;
  location /BBBB {
    proxy_pass http://192.100.100.100:82;
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. I used shepmaster/nginx-template-image which allows templating of the nginx.conf files using the environment variables provided by linking two containers.